# Product description text on woocommerce is not aligned to the left

Tags: woocommerce

Currently one of my product page the text in product description is not aligned left although i have cleared all HTML links from the text and aligned it left.

https://www.dezign-lab.com/product/12000mah-fast-portable-charger-battery-pack-dual-usb/

Is there a formula to do this? Or is there any coding? I'm not an expert.

But i've been googling to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, copy and paste onto a microsoft word. Remove all format, and then copy and paste as text. The alignment will be back to normal